# Routing in Windows XP with IP restriction

Tags: windows-xp, routing, security-policy

I have Windows XP with two connections (e.g. A and B).

What's the easiest way to make Windows XP act as a gateway to B for one and only one given computer (IP) from A?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at internet connection sharing and the WIndows firewall.  The first will allow you to route others to the internet and the latter will allow you to restrict which hosts can access the connection.